# Parfor error- File not accessible by workers

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gpu

Here I have code where I am getting error while running my full code.(I am running this code into MATLAB)

```
parfor I=1:N

  parfor J=1:M

      x(I,J)=I*DX;

      y(I,J)=J*DY;

      axis([11.175 324.076 10.785 311.98])

      plot (x(I,J),y(I,J),'o', U3, V3, '*')
   end 
end
```

Error Definition are like this 
An ***Undefined Function*** error was thrown on the workers for 'x'.  This might be
because the file containing 'x' is not accessible on the workers.  Use
addAttachedFiles(pool, files) to specify the required files to be attached.
See the documentation for 'parallel.Pool/addAttachedFiles' for more details.

Caused by:
    Undefined function or variable "x".

Please help me with the problem.

Worker is referring to the GPU and CPU cores so please don't confuse with that. I am rining this code on my inbuilt GPU+CPU computer. The problem is its taking x as a function but in my application is coordinates. I hope now question is more clear.

Comment: can you provide a small sample from all the relevant data so we can test your code and reproduce the error?

Comment: Your problem might be that you are nesting `parfor` loops. I don't think MATLAB allows this. Can you try replacing the inner loop with a regular `for`?

Comment: I tried replacing inner loop with regular but problem still exists.

Comment: poolobj = gcp;
addAttachedFiles(poolobj,{'myFun1.m','myFun2.m'})